# Chat UI let us reply to deleted messages until we reload the page

Tags: bug, chat, reply

I just noticed I can reply to a deleted message in chat, while this wasn't possible before, i.e. the reply function used to disappear when the message was deleted.

Evidence can be found [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27066125#27066125), [here](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4491567#4491567) and [here](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4491582#4491582). It seems that the reply doesn't ping the author of the deleted message, but it does convert to their name, so it gives me the smell of a bug. There may be something more serious broken.

If it helps, I'm using Chrome version 47.0.2526.111 m, though I doubt that's relevant.

---

**Update:** It seems if the message was deleted before you loaded the chat page, the reply isn't possible. Nonetheless, the previous functionality is missing and it would be surprising to see this as a new feature.

Comment: Did you hit the reply button before the message was deleted?

Comment: No @Cat; it was after the message was deleted.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this... until I refreshed the page of the browser window. Now it is no longer possible. Perhaps a temporary issue?

Comment: Related bug: if a message that was a reply is itself later deleted, the fact that it was a reply to a given message still remains publicly known on mouseover.

Comment: @Catija six and half years later... No, not temporary. :-)

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog That it still remains a reply is, IMO, desirable functionality. User's don't get any more information than what message ID it's replying to and the embedded `@` username. I don't see why that's an issue. I certainly wouldn't consider it a bug.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard Why do you consider this important enough to bounty? This seems like a *really minor* UI bug. I mean, sure, it should be fixed, but "meh". If you actually do post the reply, you get feedback that the reply wasn't complete, because the formatting doesn't include the `@<username>` and it's not marked as a reply. Why is it more important to spend developer time on this than other bugs/issues?

Comment: @Makyen because it's annoying old bug, and I hope if a developer will actually be assigned to it and look into the chat code, they'll also fix more bugs while at it.